# To change accordingly to landscape/portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a date/time picker which I want them to react according based on its layout.

Consider on landscape mode:

[image]

This is a perfect placement of what I want it to be. However if I turn it over to portrait mode, I get something like below: part of the time is missing.

[image]

My current code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/DarkGrey" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/custom_datePicker"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/custom_timePicker"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Done"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:theme="@style/General.Button">
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Changing the orientation of inner LinearLayout to Vertical would achieve what I want for portrait mode, but it messes up during landscape mode, vice versa.

What's an alternative way to this? Is it possible to change the layout's orientation programmatically whenever the screen mode turns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When screen orientation change than activity again recreated so  do this :

```
int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
 //code for portrait mode
} else {
//code for landscape mode
}
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks alot! Short and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **layout-land** directory that contains landscape layouts of your screens. In this case you would place the original layout inside the **layout-land** directory and place the `orientation:vertical` layout inside your **layout** folder.

[The Android documentation has information on how to support different screens](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)