# Orientation issue in Android 7.1.1 and above

Tags: android, android-manifest, orientation, android-os-handler

When the app is launched in landscape mode it is opening in landscape mode and switching back to portrait evethough orientation is set to portrait programatically. 
I suppose app should stay in portrait mode no matter in which mode you launch when screen orientation is set to portrait programatically.
I know if we set screen orientaion to portrait in Manifest
will solve this but I need to set orientaion programatically. Let me know if anyone faced this issue or have any idea to fix this. 
This is happening only when app is launched. Next time when the screen is rotated it is working fine.

Below is the code I am using to lock orientaion to portrait,

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

this code working fine in below Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Did you tried to set the orientation from manifest?

Comment: @TarlanAhad if we set screen orientaion to portrait in Manifest will solve this but I need to set orientaion programatically

Comment: have look [my_ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47175695/5110595)

Comment: try to add this in your **onStart()** method `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: I tried same code it work fine android api 26 as well as 27. I add `if(requestedOrientation != ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            return
        }`, and I am using kotlin.

Comment: @TarlanAhad i have add setRequestedOrientation in onCreate(). onCreate will run before onStart life cycle method

Comment: @ArchitSureja i'm directly setting portrait but it is working

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me on all devices:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
} ... enter code here ...
```