# Launch view in landscape orientation for the first time

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I want my view to launch in landscape mode. But once the user changes to landscape orientation and come back to portrait, I want my view to behave normally and change orientations according to device orientation.

Basically. view should launch in landscape only for the first time and behave normally after that.

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` to store the state of user's first time , and then perform your functionality

Comment: launch in landscape mode until when??

Comment: have look [my ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47175695/5110595)

Answer (score 0):

Write at `onStart` of your Activity

[ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

```
setRequestedOrientation(YourActivity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

[ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)

```
setRequestedOrientation(YourActivity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```